# How can menu tabs be relocated to another region?

Tags: 7, theming, routes

I want to move menu tabs to occur in the main menu region instead of immediately above the content.  I cannot identify a block that contains them.  Is there a module, template location or a hook for controlling their display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I cannot identify a block that contains them." There is not a block that contains these. In Drupal 7, these tabs are a variable called $tabs found in /modules/system/page.tpl.php.

You could suppress these tabs by overriding page.tpl.php in your theme.

To put them in another region, you could:

1. Implement hook_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) in your theme's template.php or in a custom module.
2. Copy the contents of the $variables['tabs'] array key into another region.

Answer (score 3):

If you want them in a block so you can easily place them using the UI, you can use the [Local Tasks block](http://drupal.org/project/local_tasks_blocks) or [Omega Tools](http://drupal.org/project/omega_tools) (Sub module called Delta Blocks) or [Blockify](http://drupal.org/project/blockify) modules.

Answer (score 2):

They are in the $tabs variable that's available to page.tpl.php so changing where it's printing them is the quickest way.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way as well.   The breadcrumbs can be placed in a panel.  I am creating a site using the Panels Everywhere module and have bypassed the standard theming process using page.tpl.php which gives me a clean slate to work from and have created a mini panel that contains my main menu, breadcrumbs and menu tabs in one package.